# Why won't my Query run?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have quite a few similar querys which do work, i have no clue why this one won't:

As soon as i run it i get:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

...on the `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Any obvious misstakes?

```
public void BorrowMovie(int memberCardNumber)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VideoStoreDB.sdf";
    SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);

    connection.Open();
    SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
        "UPDATE Customer SET NumberBorrowedMovies = NumberBorrowedMovies+1 " +
        "WHERE MemberCardNR = @mcn)", connection);    
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcn", memberCardNumber);      
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("Movie was borrowed!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What does the `InnerException` say?

Comment: You will have to excuse me Simon, but i don't know what the InnerException is, yet... I'm new at C# and visual studio. @Simon Whitehead.

Comment: Hopefully this is the `InnerExeption`: `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 92,Token in error = > ]` @SimonWhitehead :)

Comment: How to find [Inner Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdwz4c0s(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: @paqogomez, well that was for VB.Net... :)

Comment: Oops! :) well.. `ex.InnerException` is still the answer regardless of language.  Also you can look for the property of InnerException in your VS error details when an error is thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have unbalanced parentheses:

```
SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
    "UPDATE Customer SET NumberBorrowedMovies = NumberBorrowedMovies+1 " +
    "WHERE MemberCardNR = @mcn", connection);
```

Also, you should be using `using` blocks:

```
public void BorrowMovie(int memberCardNumber)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\VideoStoreDB.sdf";
    using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
    {

    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
        "UPDATE Customer SET NumberBorrowedMovies = NumberBorrowedMovies+1 " +
        "WHERE MemberCardNR = @mcn)", connection))
    {   
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mcn", memberCardNumber);      
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // connection.Close(); no longer needed
    } // command
    } // connection
    Console.WriteLine("Movie was borrowed!");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Oh wow.. couldn't see that at all! Nw.

Comment: Oh c'mon.......(hate towards myself) Thank you very much John for that!

Comment: Why should i be using blocks? @John Saunders

Comment: For extra credit, answer the question "what did the InnerException" say? Hint: for troubleshooting purposes _only_: catch the exception, display it with `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: @htmlNewbie, because the ADO objects aren't getting disposed properly otherwise, please see my blog post here: http://learncsharp.org/how-to-properly-and-safely-access-a-database-with-ado-net/

Comment: To prevent resource leaks.